# Dijkstra's full algorithm using BFS and dictionary bug

Tags: algorithm, graph, clojure, graph-theory, dijkstra

Using dictionaries, graphs, and lists, I'm attempting to implement the Dijkstra algorithm with BFS in Clojure. The issue is that I can't get it to work correctly; it won't work when I ask it to return the solution with weights, and it also won't work when I ask it to produce the graph without weights.
The problem occurs, most likely, at the BFS function; I would very appreciate any assistance with this.
I tried to search for information online and spoke with some of my classmates, but unfortunately it didn't help at all.

The files: e-roads-2020-full.clj + project.clj are in GitHub https://github.com/wfgemyd/clojure

```
;; state 0 - not encountered at all
;; state 1 - in the open queue
;; state 2 - current vertex
;; state 3 - visited

(defn al-papi [queue graph] ;;looks for the best vertex and dist
  (loop [queue queue
         best-distance nil
         best-vertex nil]
    (if (empty? queue)
      best-vertex
      (let [queue-label (first queue)
            queue-vertex (get @(:vertices graph) queue-label)]
        (if (or (nil? best-vertex) (< @(:distance queue-vertex) best-distance))
          (recur (rest queue) @(:distance queue-vertex) queue-vertex)
          (recur (rest queue) best-distance best-vertex))))))

(defn graph-bfs!
  ([graph]
   (graph-bfs! graph (first (keys @(:vertices graph)))))
  ([graph start]
   (graph-bfs! graph start (fn [vertex] nil)))
  ([graph start func]
   (graph-bfs! graph start func first))
  ([graph start func func-m]
   (let [vertices @(:vertices graph)]
     (loop [queue (list start)]
       (when (not (empty? queue))
         (let [current-label (if (= func-m al-papi)(func-m queue graph)(func-m queue))
               rest-queue (rest-queue! queue current-label)
               current-vertex (get vertices current-label)
               visited-status (:visited current-vertex)
               current-neighbors @(:neighbors current-vertex)
               unseen-neighbors (filter
                                  (fn [label]
                                    (= @(:visited (get vertices label)) 0))
                                  current-neighbors)
               ]
           (dosync (ref-set visited-status 2))
           (func current-vertex)
           (dosync (ref-set visited-status 3))
           (doseq [label unseen-neighbors]
             (dosync
               (ref-set (:visited (get vertices label)) 1)))
           (recur (concat rest-queue unseen-neighbors))))))))


(defn graph-dijkstra-mark! [graph finish use-weights]
  (let [vertices @(:vertices graph)
        start-vertex (get vertices finish)]
    (graph-reset! graph)
    (dosync
      (ref-set (:distance start-vertex) 0))
    (if (not use-weights)
      (graph-bfs! graph
                  finish
                  (fn [vertex]
                    (let [next-distance (inc @(:distance vertex))]
                      (doseq [neighbor-label @(:neighbors vertex)]
                        (let [neighbor (get vertices neighbor-label)]
                          (if (= @(:visited neighbor) 0)
                            (dosync
                              (ref-set (:distance neighbor) next-distance))))))))
      (graph-bfs! graph
                  finish
                  (fn [vertex]
                    (doseq [neighbor-label @(:neighbors vertex)]
                      (let [neighbor (get vertices neighbor-label)
                            next-distance (+ @(:distance vertex) (get-edge-weight graph (:label vertex) neighbor-label))]
                        (println "There is bfs!")
                        (when (or (= @(:visited neighbor) 0) (> @(:distance neighbor) next-distance))
                          (dosync
                            (ref-set (:distance neighbor) next-distance))))))
                  al-papi))))
```

Comment: I like [this Dijkstra implementation](https://www.ummels.de/2014/06/08/dijkstra-in-clojure/) without mutable state using a [clojure.data.priority-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map). It returns a map from vertex to distance. Can be modified to find the distance of the shortest route. It does not return the route though.

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug, it was in the back trace function, it was returning the ref and not the actual data that was needed in the function, plus the function "al-papi" was returning the best-vertex and not the :label of the best-vertex.